# Function Receiving Trash

Tags: c, parameters

I'm trying to make a function on a menu that prints half a triangle with a character chosen by the user, but when it receives the parameters by reference it receives trash, and can't see why. I will appreciate immensely if someone can help me.

```
case 2: do{system("cls");

    cuadro (1,1,78,24);
    gotoxy(20,10);printf("Please enter number from 3 to 10 and character wanted:");
    scanf("%d %d", &num, &car);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(num<3||num>10||car>255||car<0){
        gotoxy(20,10);printf("Not what asked, Enter Again.");
        fflush(stdin);
        getchar();
        }
    }while(num<3||num>10||car>255||car<0);
    Tri(&num,&car);
    break;
```

And this is the function:

```
void Tri(int*num,int*car){
    int f=1, c=1;
    system("cls");
    while(f<=num){
    c=1;
    while(c<=f){
    printf("%c",car);
    c++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    f++;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing pointers to num and car, &num and &car.  Inside function Tri, num and car are pointers to the values.  Therefore, inside Tri, change to deref.  For example, change "while(f<=num)" to "while(f<=*num)" and "printf("%c,car)" to "printf("%c,*car)"

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have reference parameters.  When you pass `car` directly to `printf` you are printing the value of `car` itself, which is a *pointer* to the variable holding the value you actually wanted to print.  Use `printf("%c", *car)` to print the value pointed-to by `car`.

I see several other bugs.  Also, it is not clear to me why you wrote `Tri` to take pointer arguments in the first place.

Comment: Because it was the requirements of the practice, still thanks for the comments and for the help.